# sha256sum: 'standard input': no properly formatted checksum lines found

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to verify an installer by typing this command.

```
grep node-vx.y.z.tar.gz SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c -
```

But I get a response like this from Terminal

```
sha256sum: 'standard input': no properly formatted checksum lines found
```

Obviously, I already have SHASUMS256.txt file and on the right path on Terminal(MacOS).

Also prior to this, I've already installed CoreUtils from brew by running this command.

```
brew install coreutils
```

So what does `'standard input': no properly formatted checksum lines found` mean in this context on MacOS Terminal?

Answer (score 3):

In my macOS Monterey Version 12.61 I have to add an asterisk prior to the filename, in this way:

```
36a2c2c01723151b36987e377ebfc152337cc61699eaa6bf45d9460a4c3e216b *nifi-toolkit-1.17.0-bin.zip
```

And then run the command:

```
shasum -a 256 -c input.txt
```

Finally, I got this:

```
nifi-toolkit-1.17.0-bin.zip: OK
```

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you posted the contents of the file:

- SHASUMS256.txt

If it is properly formatted it should contain a line that looks something like:

> 09ac98ea433e8cb19d09ead1a0bd439cafb1c3e4cb699af04b4e4da1f6ca3f02 node-vx.y.z.tar.gz

You could get your stderr output for 2 possible reasons.

1. The line in SHASUMS256.txt is not formatted correctly. It should be formatted as `<ChecksumHash> <Filename>` without the <>s.
2. The output from your grep search is blank (no output because grep returned no matches). This is more likely and I would suggest running the grep command by itself first to see what the output is prior to piping it into sha256sum.